# Error running linux container on windows 2019 server AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2019

I'm having problem while running Linux container on Windows Server 2019, AWS.

Following is the error:

`failed to register layer: failed to start service utility VM (applydiff 7867715a779e14ed8af41d812471a62615cb810cbce3df69a4ed0d2036086d7b): container 7867715a779e14ed8af41d812471a62615cb810cbce3df69a4ed0d2036086d7b_svm encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed. (0xc0370102) extra info: {"SystemType":"container","Name":"7867715a779e14ed8af41d812471a62615cb810cbce3df69a4ed0d2036086d7b_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\Program Files\Linux Containers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"bootx64.efi"},"ContainerType":"linux","TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true}`

Note: Hyper-V is activated.

Comment: If you're on AWS anyways, would it be easier to get a Linux EC2 instance to run your Linux container(s)?

Comment: You're right. But there are some system requirements.